# Прямоугольник вне класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Уважаемые! Возникла проблема при выполнении задания на СИ#. У меня стоит задача нарисовать прямоугольник вне основного класса Form. Как мне это сделать? В задании требуется использовать Наследование.

```
class Geometry 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    public double thickness;
    public int coordinatesX, coordinatesY;
    public int R, G, B;
    public Geometry(int coordinatesX, int coordinatesY, double thickness ,int R,int G ,int B)
    {
        coordinatesX = rand.Next(0,100);
        coordinatesY = rand.Next(0,100);
        thickness = rand.Next(1,10);
        this.coordinatesX = coordinatesX;
        this.coordinatesY = coordinatesY;
        this.thickness = thickness;
        this.R = R;
        this.G = G;
        this.B = B;      
    }       
    public void ChangeColor()
    {            
        R = rand.Next(0, 255);
        G = rand.Next(0, 255);
        B = rand.Next(0, 255);
    }
}
class Rectangle1 : Geometry
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int height, widht;
    public Rectangle1(int coordinatesX, int coordinatesY, double thickness,int R,int G,int B):base(coordinatesX, coordinatesY, thickness,R,G,B)
    {

    }
    public void PaintRectangle()
    {            
        height = rand.Next(1, 10);
        widht = rand.Next(1, 10);            
        Rectangle Paint = new Rectangle(coordinatesX - widht/2 , coordinatesY + height/2 , coordinatesX + widht/2 , coordinatesY - height/2);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**вне основного класса Form** - тут же сказано, просто вынеси код за пределы класса формы.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ...
    }
    ...
}

...

class Rectangle1 : Geometry
{
    ...
}
```

Если я правильно понял вашу идею о наследовании, то можно так сделать:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Rectangle rectangle;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rectangle = new Rectangle
        {
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Size = new Size(100, 25)
        };

        pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var graph = e.Graphics;

        rectangle.Paint(graph);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

public abstract class GraphObject
{
    public abstract Point Location { get; set; }
    public abstract Size Size { get; set; }
    public abstract Color Color { get; set; }
    public abstract void Paint(Graphics e);
}

public class Rectangle : GraphObject
{
    private Point location;
    private Size size;
    private Color color;

    public Rectangle()
    {
        this.location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.size = new Size(0, 0);
        this.color = Color.Black;
    }

    public Rectangle(Point location, Size size, Color? color = null)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color == null ? Color.Black : (Color)color;
    }

    public override Point Location { get => location; set => location = value; }
    public override Size Size { get => size; set => size = value; }
    public override Color Color { get => color; set => color = value; }

    public override void Paint(Graphics e)
    {
        e.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), new System.Drawing.Rectangle(location, size));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну покажите как это сделать. Как нарисовать прямоугольник в другом классе.

Comment: @ГусьГа как-то так

Comment: Спасибочки пупсик

Comment: @ГусьГа если мой ответ помог, не могли бы вы его отметить, как верный.